# not able to run aws ssm run-command as different user other than root

Tags: amazon-web-services, runcommand, ssm

I want to sync a s3 bucket on ec2 instance and I want to do it using ssm run-command. The problem is ssm run-command always executes as root user which does not have s3 permissions. how to run ssm run-commands as ubuntu user.

Comment: solved it, I added a bucket policy with the ssm role as principle

Comment: Can you use SSM with a different user though?

Comment: I haven't tried with different user.

Comment: One workaround I've used is to run the command `runuser -l ubuntu -c '<command here>'`. It's hideous really, but it does work.